# Can't deploy maven restful Upload file

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, glassfish

```
package Restful.Demo.UploadFile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("UploadFile")
public class Upload {

    @GET
    @Path("/upload1")
    public String hello()
    {
        return "hello";
    }

    @POST 
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)// use to upload file
    public Response UploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream inputfile,
                              @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition filemetadetail) 
    {

            int statuscode=200;
            String fileLocation="e://Restful/"+filemetadetail.getFileName();
            writeFile(inputfile, fileLocation);
            String output="File uploaded to "+fileLocation;
            return Response.status(statuscode).entity(output).build(); 

    }
    /*
     * @param inputFile the file you want to upload
     * @param fileLocation where  file will be uploaded 
     * @return 0 - success 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void writeFile(InputStream inputFile,String fileLocation) 
    {
        OutputStream output=null;
        try
        {
            output=new FileOutputStream(new File(fileLocation));
            int read=0;
            byte[] bytes=new byte[1024];
            //read 
            while((read=inputFile.read(bytes))!=-1)
                output.write(bytes, 0, read);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Hello.
I'm peter and newbie in Restful webserver.
Above is my uploadfile code using restful api - Jersey run on Glassfish server
I'm getting this error while I'm trying to publish the war to glassfish server

> java.lang.Exception: deploy is failing=Application with name
>   [UploadFile] is not deployed  at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassFishServerBehaviour.publishDeployedDirectory(GlassFishServerBehaviour.java:603)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassFishServerBehaviour.publishModuleForGlassFishV3(GlassFishServerBehaviour.java:830)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.glassfish.GlassFishServerBehaviour.publishModule(GlassFishServerBehaviour.java:790)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publishModule(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1091)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publishModules(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:1183)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:987)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3182)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:355)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56)

can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: You provided too little information to be able to help you. Post `web.xml`, what version of Jersey, Servlet, Glassfish, ..., you're running.

Comment: i'm not using servlet . just an HTML file with post form .

Comment: glassfish 4.1.1 . Jersery 2.26

Comment: Edit the question and post the relevant content of `web.xml`.

Comment: sorry . there is no web.xml in my project. There's only pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

To be able make your resource class to work you need to do some things.

1. Either you provide an `Application` subclass or the `web.xml` deployment descriptor.
2. To be able to use multipart module you need to enable this feature on your server code. Here is an extract from the [documentation page](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#multipart):

> 9.3.1.2. Registration
>
> Before you can use capabilities of the jersey-media-multipart module in your client/server code, you need to register MultiPartFeature.

That said, I have added the following `web.xml` on an example and I could deploy the application on Glassfish 4:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
version="3.1">

<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <!-- please see modified package name -->
            <param-value>restful.demo.uploadfile</param-value> 
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>

        <!-- you can choose your favorite name here!! -->
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>    
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Notes:

- See the commented parts above and try to modify your code accordingly.
- There are some naming conventions in Java that you should be aware of (see [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) document for more details):

  1. In Java package names are in lowercase  letters
  2. Method names begin with lowercase letter